# How can i fill a shape created by a user at runtime using canvas

Tags: javascript, canvas

I am using sketch.js to enable a user to draw something on the canvas while the page is live.

I wanted to know if it would be possible to allow the user to draw a shape and then fill it with some color while the program is running

Answer (score 0):

From what I read on [the site](http://intridea.github.io/sketch.js/), this script allows you only to free sketch something, not to draw specific shapes. If you'd like to draw a shape to the canvas you should use [EaselJS](http://www.createjs.com/easeljs)

```
var graphics = new createjs.Graphics().beginFill("#ff0000").drawRect(0, 0, 100, 100);
var shape = new createjs.Shape(graphics);
```

Or you could use directly the canvas, without EaselJS

```
var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
ctx.fillRect(20,20,150,100);
```